# UINavigationController with strange behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an application with the following structure,
[image]

Each of the three compoenentes has a UINavigationController associated with.

This application is intended to be identical to facebook.

My problem is that in landscape mode, the "POP" actions of navigations have a strange performance, making the animation from the bottom to the top, as if the navigation had not done the rotation, despite the layout being changed to landscape.

I put all the navigation controller with:

```
  [navCenter.navigationBar setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
 [navCenter shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:YES];
```

Any idea why this happen?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
  If i remove my

```
[self addChildViewController:self.mainConteinar];
```

The animation works good. But now, the NavigationBars didn't resize.

Answer (score 1):

You should check all your

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

What you describe sounds as if you forgot to return YES for landscape orientation in one of your child view controllers.

Comment: I put it in all of them. Check in all of them. I have another strange behavior, when i make an PoP action, in UINavigation 1, it makes the UINavigation 2 make the same animation, at the same time. Both make an animation from bottom to up, although only the first change his content